# Instance property attributes in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, properties

How to add property attributes e.g **nonatomic** in swift?

Property Declaration in Objective-C

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
```

How to declare above instance property with nonatomic attribute in swift?

Comment: Swift properties are non atomic by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift properties are **non atomic** by default.

*Atomicity property attributes (atomic and nonatomic) are not reflected in the corresponding Swift property declaration, but the atomicity guarantees of the Objective-C implementation still hold when the imported property is accessed from Swift.*

source: [medium.com](https://medium.com/@YogevSitton/atomic-vs-non-atomic-properties-crash-course-d11c23f4366c)

Answer (score 0):

Swift does not have that in the same extent.

You can specify some modifiers though.

```
var value: Int
private var value: Int
weak var value: Int?
lazy var value: Int = 0
```

etc.